# How is stack depth calculated?

Tags: apex, limits

We currently have a limit of Maximum Stack Depth of `1000`.

I assuming that we could call a method, that calls another method, and then another one 1000 times, so 999 "nested" methods should be fine.

Example:

```java
private Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectType(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult rq, Integer i){
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult rs = rq.getSobjectType().getDescribe();
    if(i == 0) return rs;
    else return objectType(rs, --i);
}

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
objectType(r, 998);
```

If I run this on the Developer Console Execute Anonymous window I get the error:

> System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 1001

But if I change the last bit to

```
objectType(r, 997)
```

Then it's a success.

I was under the impression I could it with `999` (initial call + plus 999 recursive calls), but it does not seem to be the case.

So my question is: **What are the 2 "hidden" stack?**

Comment: Initial Call + 997 works , ie total (998). One would code calling Execute anon method. Thats 1. Bringing total to 999.

Comment: But then initial call + 998 should work too. 1000 is still allowed, it only fails on 1001.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

1. When you say 997, it runs 998 times counting initial call (actually not hidden)
2. The call to the `class` constructor
3. Execute anonymous

This can be tested in `Dev console > open log > Debug > View log panels > Execution Overview > Executed Units`

Comment: hum... from my test it looks like it's not the class constructor but 1. the call to the tollingAPI 2 the call to the execute_anonymous_apex method and then the 998 sobjectType calls. 

nice!